# Error on R formula for data computation from csv file

Tags: r, excel, csv, formula

I am getting this error "non-numeric argument to binary operator" in R.
For context, I am trying to devide the contents of two variables in a csv file.

Say, A file with columns, b and c.
I try to get them by:

```
new_data <- read.csv("A")
new_data_ave <- new_data$b/new_data$c
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a function called `csv.open()` but no matter - to answer your question directly, since you store the data into an object named `new_data` you need to reference that for your calculations. i.e. `new_data$b / new_data$c`

Comment: Will update my question. Thanks for pointong those out

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(head(new_data))` as part of your question.

Comment: ^ you might also look at `str(new_data)`. Are `b` and `c` both numeric like you expect?